Is it halal/ haram to use Windows without activation?
Someone had made a design for the stickers on a computer with Coral Draw, but the windows of the computer was not activated. There was a watermark on the screen.
According to term no.5 of Microsoft.
Breifly as per term no 5 of Microsoft, we can use this software only if it is properly licensed and properly activated with geniune products key.
My question is that my income will halal/ haram by selling the stickers (whose design made on that computer )?
